# Unexpected T_Variable occurs

Tags: php

What is wrong in this highlighted syntax?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("student") or die("could not connect");


//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq)

//here
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE registration LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search!");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == o){
        $output = 'There was no search results!';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $fname = $row['firstname'];
            $lname = $row['surname'];
            $id = $row['registration'];

            $output .= '<div> '.$id.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>';

}
?>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search for students.."
    <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>


<?php print("$output");?>
</body>
</html>
```

please help....

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: See the line above of `//here
$query...`. Don't always believe the line number it says the error's on ;-)

Comment: You're missing a `;` semicolon go find it!

Comment: You are also missing a `}`. Please don't use Stack Overflow to debug your code.

Comment: I believe you have an "o" instead of "0" (zero): if($count == o){

Comment: So many things wrong with this.

Comment: Look it's pretty easy all your answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/3933332 you just have to read it and find it! I think instead of giving you your answer it's better to learn what the error means, what's going on so next time you can solve this yourself!

Comment: @FelixKling *"You are also missing a `}`"* - Missing two braces actually. Something that wasn't noted in the "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a semi-colon :

```
//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq)
```

should be

```
//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
```

Comment: *"Also, looks like the line that directly follows is missing one, too..."* - Being? Who upvoted this? Fix it all, not just 1/2 way ;-)

Comment: Thanks rm_vanda & others for rectify the code. Actually i am novice in php. so i'm facing this type of problem. If this type of problem is not allowed in stackoverflow then i'll surely left the site.
Please let me know.

Comment: @Nasim: Yes, avoid asking questions about syntax errors. The basic syntax is the very least we expect someone to know.